# Sql server version error...655 version needed but you computer has 612 or earlier version ? error

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi i have a error like " dbFileName cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. "

what should i do ? some friend of mine done a project but i guess he done it with sql 2008 and i have sql 2005  is that the reason why i got this error? can i fix it ? if i setup a newer version of sql does it will solve the problem?
  www.microsoft.com/express/Database/default.aspx#Installation_Options  here sql server 2008 R2 express is available can it be the solution? 
thank you...

by the way i found a link of an update http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E1109AEF-1AA2-408D-AA0F-9DF094F993BF&displaylang=en  is this a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS update in the link is not a solution to your problem. You'll need that update though if you want to use VS to work with a SQL Server 2008 project. And you will have to work with SQL Server 2008 if you want to use your friend's database. To solve your problem you'll need to upgrade to SQL Server 2008. Express edition is fine, as long as the database is less than 4Gb in size. Note that if you continue to work on this database, you won't be bale to deploy your solution to a hosting that is based on SQL 2005, since they won't be able to use your database.

But the real problem you face here is the fact that you treat MDF files as source. You should develop exclusively using T-SQL scripts to deploy your database, and then you won't have *any* of these problems. You can use a [application versioned schema deployment strategy](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/), or you can use a Visual Studio Database Edition project and deploy using vsdbcmd.exe and .dbschema files. Any of this solutions will be way ahead of actually checking in MDF files, exchanging MDFs between team members or copying MDFs at deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

SThe database has been attached to a sql server 2008 instance. You cant attach it back to a sql 2005 server. ee this link for more details:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/01ed3b1c-6f29-4518-a3a4-e4e35decc05f

You can download an express version of Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to open it without installing the same or later version that was used to create the file; you can use the free SQL Server 2008 Express Edition if it the database is not too large.